# How to fix SLO with passport-saml that works on first logout but not on subsequent logouts

Tags: express, adfs, passport-saml

I have to connect an application to my company's ADFS server.  I am using passport-saml for SSO and SLO.  SSO works, and SLO works on the first logout only.  I am trying to make SLO work every time a user logs out.

I have been searching high and low for a solution to this problem, but it evades me.  Here's the details:

1. I clear the cookies in the browser to start with a clean slate.
2. I login to my application which redirects to ADFS' login page
3. Enter user credentials and then ADFS redirects back to my app's homepage
4. I log out of my app and a request is sent to the ADFS server killing my session locally and on ADFS, I am then redirected back to my app's homepage
5. I log in again and this works as intended
6. I logout but this time I am sent to my ADFS server's logout page.

Further inspection shows that ADFS is not clearing its cookies so the ADFS session stays live.

I have used Firefox's SAML viewer plugin to watch what is happening and here are my findings:

On a successful logout:

**HTTP:**

GET https://myadfs.org/adfs/ls/?wa=wsignout1.0 HTTP/1.1
Host: myadfs.org
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Referer: https://example.com/dashboard/data
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: MSISAuth=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; SamlSession=aHR0cHMlM2ElMmYlMmZmcGNkcmRldi5tb2ZmaXR0Lm9yZyZGYWxzZSZDdWtyYXNTRCYmJiYmXzFkZjY4M2RhLTM4NTktNDVjNS04ODNkLTA3NmRiYTdiMjk3Yg==; MSISAuthenticated=NC8xNi8yMDE5IDExOjI2OjI4IEFN; MSISLoopDetectionCookie=MjAxOS0wNC0xNjoxMToyNjoyOFpcMQ==
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Location: https://example.com:443/login?SAMLRequest=lZLfa4MwEMf%2fFcl71KjxR7BCqS9C18I69rCXEjXpZJq4XCz982crY6yMwh7vuO9973N3OfChH9lWn%2fRkn8XnJMA6VblCR%2bpzQqWUOKWE4igMUlz7nGKexHUYJdSnKUXOqzDQabVCgesjpwKYRKXAcmXnlE8y7EeYxC%2bEsCBmYeamCX1DTjm7dIrbm%2fLd2hGY58mxaU0rzu6gpeysdbU5eb0%2bdQo5G61AXHtORjHNoQOm%2bCCA2YYd1k9bNtuzZilik4JRNJ3sRIucnbZ7tTdraYW5HykkPyNdhl4Bu23jsctotNWN7lGR33DNIn0s4gDCXHFRccWdac04Auh7XN5K8ObSc9cI8KyZwObeYlPku7ltVf7TbjN9GA6HMvcWeZEvFz8IuB6uUq24FEfSyjgNW47DlGY4og3F6RxjP4nbmid1kCV17v2h%2fE7%2beqDiCw%3d%3d&Signature=pT%2fSUpslARJlvOCah5VzZk4stZLIREyHmUFOO4siHUbkL5eJG4QsfYj9Pq%2bwxnOaPaevYkmiXq0rft3drTzJHspns9UbucyYQvEaSAZVmRTTyfPC3Z0EgVGSvtr0JL3nuDPsq2IfbToseuQQtJFsA%2b94D8KtaLjtUJxiMcQMHyg2yR00Ac3NGt9AsRg1X73X%2frt0XZDN9bSt4R8t%2bt2Yl2UsZsL4GHTGk7RbN3AUrYHsLtKeuN07umXqX3otVtHo%2f9tx2w2h1glYycYbFCk%2bWjox8Mej%2fiLLkpAhw9EXlhiTGrEJ2%2bcYvnQxGokOsz2vXEOoc3%2fhle27LuTPFMN9yw%3d%3d&SigAlg=http%3a%2f%2fwww.w3.org%2f2001%2f04%2fxmldsig-more%23rsa-sha256
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
P3P: ADFS doesn't have P3P policy, please contact your site's admin for more details
Set-Cookie: SamlSession=; expires=Mon, 15 Apr 2019 11:26:39 GMT; path=/adfs
SamlLogout=aHR0cCUzYSUyZiUyZnJwcHNzb2Rldi5tb2ZmaXR0Lm9yZyUyZmFkZnMlMmZzZXJ2aWNlcyUyZnRydXN0Pz8/aHR0cHMlM2ElMmYlMmZmcGNkcmRldi5tb2ZmaXR0Lm9yZyZGYWxzZSZDdWtyYXNTRCYmJiYmXzFkZjY4M2RhLTM4NTktNDVjNS04ODNkLTA3NmRiYTdiMjk3Yj9fNTBhMTVmZmYtODUxNS00MzI4LWIwYTUtYTc2YjM0NzUwNTg1P3VybiUzYW9hc2lzJTNhbmFtZXMlM2F0YyUzYVNBTUwlM2EyLjAlM2FzdGF0dXMlM2FTdWNjZXNz; path=/adfs; HttpOnly; Secure
MSISAuthenticated=; expires=Mon, 15 Apr 2019 11:26:39 GMT; path=/adfs
MSISAuth=; expires=Mon, 15 Apr 2019 11:26:39 GMT; path=/adfs
ReturnUrl=aHR0cHM6Ly9ycHBzc29kZXYubW9mZml0dC5vcmc6NDQzL2FkZnMvbHMvP3dhPXdzaWdub3V0MS4w; path=/adfs; HttpOnly; Secure
MSISSignoutProtocol=U2FtbA==; expires=Tue, 16 Apr 2019 11:36:39 GMT; path=/adfs; HttpOnly; Secure
Date: Tue, 16 Apr 2019 11:26:39 GMT

**SAML:**

```xml
<samlp:LogoutRequest ID="_50a15fff-8515-4328-b0a5-a76b34750585"
                     Version="2.0"
                     IssueInstant="2019-04-16T11:26:39.875Z"
                     Destination="https://example.com/login"
                     Consent="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:consent:unspecified"
                     NotOnOrAfter="2019-04-16T11:31:39.875Z"
                     xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
                     > <Issuer xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">http://myadfs.org/adfs/services/trust</Issuer> <NameID xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">USERNAME</NameID> <samlp:SessionIndex>_1df683da-3859-45c5-883d-076dba7b297b</samlp:SessionIndex> </samlp:LogoutRequest>
```

On subsequent, unsuccessful logouts:

**HTTP:**

GET https://myadfs.org/adfs/ls/?wa=wsignout1.0 HTTP/1.1
Host: myadfs.org
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Referer: https://example.com/dashboard/data
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: MSISLoopDetectionCookie=MjAxOS0wNC0xNjoxMToyODoyNlpcMQ==; SamlLogout=aHR0cCUzYSUyZiUyZnJwcHNzb2Rldi5tb2ZmaXR0Lm9yZyUyZmFkZnMlMmZzZXJ2aWNlcyUyZnRydXN0Pz8/aHR0cHMlM2ElMmYlMmZmcGNkcmRldi5tb2ZmaXR0Lm9yZyZGYWxzZSZDdWtyYXNTRCYmJiYmXzFkZjY4M2RhLTM4NTktNDVjNS04ODNkLTA3NmRiYTdiMjk3Yj9fNTBhMTVmZmYtODUxNS00MzI4LWIwYTUtYTc2YjM0NzUwNTg1P3VybiUzYW9hc2lzJTNhbmFtZXMlM2F0YyUzYVNBTUwlM2EyLjAlM2FzdGF0dXMlM2FTdWNjZXNz; ReturnUrl=aHR0cHM6Ly9ycHBzc29kZXYubW9mZml0dC5vcmc6NDQzL2FkZnMvbHMvP3dhPXdzaWdub3V0MS4w; MSISSignoutProtocol=U2FtbA==; MSISAuth=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; SamlSession=aHR0cHMlM2ElMmYlMmZmcGNkcmRldi5tb2ZmaXR0Lm9yZyZGYWxzZSZDdWtyYXNTRCYmJiYmX2NlNDAwODQxLTA2ZDItNDI3Ni05MTRlLWU5N2ExYWRlZmQzZQ==; MSISAuthenticated=NC8xNi8yMDE5IDExOjI4OjI2IEFN
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache,no-store
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 8957
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Date: Tue, 16 Apr 2019 11:28:45 GMT

**SAML:**

NO SAML SENT

You will see that on a successful logout ADFS sets the cookies to clear them while an unsuccessful logout does not.  Also, the unsuccessful logout does not send the SAML logout request.

Lastly, when I clear the cookies in the browser, the first login/logout session will work as intended again, and all subsequent logouts will not.  I can see the cookies are retained on subsequent logouts as ADFS is not getting the SAML logout request.  I just don't understand how this works on the first logout but not the following logouts.  I have looked in and out of passport-saml's code but can't seem to find the issue.

Any assistance would be great.

Here is my passport.js setup:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const passport = require('passport');
const SamlStrategy = require('passport-saml').Strategy;
require('dotenv').config();

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user);
});

passport.use(new SamlStrategy({
    entryPoint: 'https://myadfs.org/adfs/ls',
    issuer: 'https://example.com',
    callbackUrl: process.env.NODESERVERURL + ':' + process.env.PORT + '/authenticate/adfs/postResponse',
    privateCert: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/private/keys/fpcdr.key', 'utf-8'),
    logoutUrl: 'https://myadfs.org/adfs/ls/?wa=wsignout1.0',
    signatureAlgorithm: 'sha256'
},
    function(profile, done) {
        const username = profile.nameID.toLowerCase();
        const email = profile['http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress'].toLowerCase();
        const sessionIndex = profile.sessionIndex;
        return done(null, {
            username,
            email,
            sessionIndex
        });
    })
);

module.exports = passport;
```

passport callbackUrl:

```
module.exports.adfsAuthenticate = function(req, res) {

    const email = req.user.email;
    const username = req.user.username;

    if (process.env.UAT === 'true') {
        res.status(302).redirect(LANDING_PAGE_REDIRECT_DEV);
    } else {
        res.status(302).redirect(LANDING_PAGE_REDIRECT_PROD);
    }
};
```

adfs logout:

```
module.exports.logout = function(req, res) {
    req.logout();
    req.session.destroy(function (err) {
        if (!err) {
            res.status(200).clearCookie('connect.sid', {path: '/'}).json({status: "Success"});
        } else { alert(err); }
    });
};
```

Comment: Did you got a fix?

Comment: @Yakalent No unfortunately I still haven't gotten this to work as I want.  The only way we have it working still is our ADFS admins always set any active session to exired whenever a user tries to login again.  The application uses its own session token as well, but the ADFS session token is still active despite the application session token becoming expired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution, shared [here](https://github.com/node-saml/passport-saml/issues/221#issuecomment-1285753685)

I found out why SLO doesn't work. I found a solution to make it work properly, im my case with Microsoft Azure (SAML-ADFS), using a database session storage. I log in from my app. Then I log out from microsoft azure ( not from my app), and it logs out nicely !

I think important to mention that there is a huge difference between the IDP logout request with all others. Most of the time, passport routes handle **user device's initiated requests** or **redirects**, That means the device's cookies comes along theses requests, which allows passport-saml to successfully retreive device's user information.

When the IDP broadcasts a logout request to relevant ISP(s), it is not always a **device request** (either initiated nor redirected). It is a simple HTTP GET request that contains a SAMLRequest. This SAMLRequest contains what the IDP uses to identify a **saml user**.

A saml user is identified using **nameID** and **nameIDFormat** profile properties.

Therefore, when a user logs in through an IDP, the app **must** store both values, nameID and nameIDFormat. You can acheive that first in you saml strategy authentication handler :

```
export const samlStrategy = new SamlStrategy({
      ...samlStrategyOptionsHere,
      logoutCallbackUrl: 'https://your.isp.com/saml/logout'
   }, 
   (profile: Profile | null | undefined, done: VerifiedCallback) => {
    
    // do login process. On successful login, don't forget 
    // to pass along nameID and nameIDFormat profile values !

    done(null, {
        userId: user.id, // in my case, my app just need to store the user id
        nameID: profile?.nameID,
        nameIDFormat: profile?.nameIDFormat
    })

});
```

Then store nameID and nameIDFormat in passport user's session ( within serialization process ) :

```
interface SessionUserData{
    userId: number,
    nameID?: string,
    nameIDFormat?: string,
}
passport.serializeUser<SessionUserData>((user: any, done) => {

    // do serialization stuff

    done(null, {
        userId: user.id,
        nameID: user?.nameID,
        nameIDFormat: user?.nameIDFormat
    })
});
```

SLO requests can then be handled properly by first retreiving passport sessions that holds the specified **saml identification**, and destroy them manually, like this :

```
interface SAMLLogoutExpectedResponse{
    profile?: Profile | null | undefined;
    loggedOut?: boolean | undefined;
}

authRouter.get('/saml/logout', async (req, res)=>{

    // req.user may not exists here, since this is a single HTTP-GET request that contains a SAMLRequest 
    // initiated by the IDP, not a user device redirection
    // use passport-saml to validate this request
    const response:SAMLLogoutExpectedResponse = await (samlStrategy._saml as SAML).validateRedirectAsync(req.query, url.parse(req.url).query)
    
    // check the « SAML USER » profile
    if( response?.profile && 
        response.profile?.nameID && 
        response.profile?.nameIDFormat && 
        response.loggedOut===true ){

        // get related session(s) if exists
        const sessionsToDestroy:string[] = ((await knex.from('sessions').where(true).select('*')) ?? []).reduce((acc:any[], session:any) => {
            const userData:any = JSON.parse(session?.data ?? {})?.passport?.user
            
            if( userData &&
                userData.nameID &&
                userData.nameIDFormat &&
                userData.nameID == response?.profile?.nameID &&
                userData.nameIDFormat == response?.profile?.nameIDFormat
                ){

                acc.push(session.session_id)
                
            }
            return acc;
        }, [])

        if(sessionsToDestroy.length){
            // destroy database session --> which invalidate any corresponding cookie on any device (if still exists)
            await knex.from('sessions').whereIn('session_id', sessionsToDestroy).delete();
        }
    }
    // if this is a IDP request, all ends here
    // if user initiated the logout request, IDP will redirect device here. Send the device somewhere coherent after successful logout
    res.redirect('/')
});
```

Voilà. I know this is a precise case, and doesn't fit to everyone. But the most important point is that a SLO callback must handle nameID and nameIDFormat values. It should not handle a device session.

Comment: thanks for the effort here.  This pointed me in the right direction after all and helped me solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have observed that there is one cookie which gets stored in browser called "MSISSignoutProtocol", if this cookie exist, the logout does not work as expected on subsequent requests.

To get it working, you might need to implement proper SAML logout which most IDP support.

Comment: Thanks @MBill I will take a look into that and see if it works.  That seems straight forward enough.